# JavaScript for Form Validation

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a form that checks for these requirements:

1. Makes sure "Full Name" and "Student ID" fields are not empty
2. Makes sure the "Email Address" field contains "@ufv.ca".

HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />    
        <meta name="description" content="Javascript Quiz"/>
         <meta name="author" content="M.Bouguerra"/>
        <meta name="keywords" content="Javascript, client side scripting"/>
        <meta name="robots" content="index,folow,noarchive"/>

        <link rel="icon" href="images/mylogo.ico"/>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/script.js"> </script>
        <title>Javascript</title>

</head>
<body onload="focus()">
<header>
    <img id="logo" src="./images/javascript.jpg" alt="Javascript Logo" title="Javascript Logo" height="200">
<hgroup >
    <h1>Javascript Overview</h1>
<h2>Multiple Choice Quiz</h2>   
</hgroup>

</header>
<nav>
    <ul  id="menu">
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="register.html">Register</a></li>
        <li><a href="quiz.html">Start Quiz</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>

</nav>
    <br>
<section >
<article>
<form  action="quiz.html" id="register" method="get" >
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Registration Form</legend>
        <ol>
            <li class="input">
                <label >Full Name</label>
                <input type="text" id="fullName" name="fullName" />
             </li>
             <li class="input">
                <label >Student ID</label>
                <input type="text" id="studentId" name="studentId" />
             </li>
            <li class="input">
                <label >Email address</label>
                <input type="text" id="email" name="email"  />
             </li>
          </ol>  
        <input type="submit" value="Start Quiz" onclick="validateRegistration()" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
    <br>

</article>
</section>
    <br>
    <br>
<footer>
&copy; 2016 M. Bouguerra
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
//Function to make "Full name" form element highlighted
function focus(){
    document.forms.register.fullName.focus();
}


//Requirements for Form Values
function validateRegistration(){
    if(document.forms.register.fullName.value==""){
        alert("You must enter your full name");
        return false; //WHY WE NEED THIS?
    }
    else if(document.forms.register.studentID.value==""){
    alert("You must provide student ID");
    return false;
    }
    else if(!document.forms.register.email.value.match(/.+@ufv.ca$/)){
        alert("You must provide a valid ufv email");
        return false;
    }
    return true; //what's this for?
}
```

When the Full Name field is empty and I click "Start Quiz" to submit the form the alert pops up to tell the user to input their full name, but still goes to the quiz page, which I don't want to happen if the form requirements aren't met.

It also seems like the statements for validating the Student ID and Email fields are not working at all.

Comment: Try doing this, remove the `action` and `method` from form and send the form in `validateRegistration()` after doing the validation.

Comment: Ok so I would add a script in the validateRegistration() function that would submit the form?

Comment: Exactly! This way, your form is submitted only if it's valid. In the current scenario, the form is being submitted irrespective of it's validity.

Comment: Also, change the type of the button from `submit` to `button`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. call validation onSubmit of the form
2. The field name is wrong document.forms.register.studentID.value should be document.forms.register.studentId.value
3. Store the error messages and display in single alert instead of checking first field and return from validation. which will fail to validate other fields.

```js
//Function to make "Full name" form element highlighted
function focus(){
    document.forms.register.fullName.focus();
}


//Requirements for Form Values
function validateRegistration(){
  var str = [];
    if(document.forms.register.fullName.value==""){
        str.push("You must enter your full name");
    }
    if(document.forms.register.studentId.value==""){
    str.push("You must provide student ID");
    }
    if(!document.forms.register.email.value.match(/.+@ufv.ca$/)){
        str.push("You must provide a valid ufv email");
    }
  if(str.length > 0) {
    alert(str.join('\n'));
    return false;
    } else { return true; }
}
```

```html
<form  action="quiz.html" id="register" method="get" onSubmit="return validateRegistration()" >
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Registration Form</legend>
        <ol>
            <li class="input">
                <label >Full Name</label>
                <input type="text" id="fullName" name="fullName" />
             </li>
             <li class="input">
                <label >Student ID</label>
                <input type="text" id="studentId" name="studentId" />
             </li>
            <li class="input">
                <label >Email address</label>
                <input type="text" id="email" name="email"  />
             </li>
          </ol>  
        <input type="submit" value="Start Quiz" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```